# What files can i remove in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, production

I'm deploying my Rails project on a hosting.

What folders and files can i safely remove from Rails project, that needed only in development ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know we can remove the documentation and test folders as they were not being used in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

`spec, test, doc, log` (only delete the contents of `log`, not the folder itself)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can remove whatever files are present inside the `.gitignore` file.

For eg, Files that are present inside the `log, tmp` folders can be removed. etc.

You'll be amazed to know what kind of memory these log files are keeping.